# Script not iterating through table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My intentions behind this are to reduce the amount of text that could be inside of a table by placing it in another div, and also by showing which cells have text and which don't. This is why the HTML structure should remain the same unless inserted by jQuery.

1. When the page loads, anything inside of the td tag is wrapped in a paragraph tag.
2. Read the paragraph tag, if there is no text, add a span tag that tells whether or not there is a quote.
3. If there is a quote, display the quote inside of a div that appears when 'View Quotes' is clicked.

At step 2. it only reads whether the first cell has text in it and not the others. How do I properly iterate through the cells to accomplish this (without changing HTML)?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var quote_cell = $("tbody td:nth-child(6)");
  var modal = $("#hidden_container");
  var modal_text = $("#hidden_container p");

  quote_cell.wrapInner("<p class='a_quote'></p>");
  if (quote_cell.text().trim() == "") {
    quote_cell.append("<span>No quote available</span>");
  } else {
    quote_cell.children().css('display', 'none')
    quote_cell.append("<span>View Quotes</span>");
  }

  quote_cell.click(function() {
    var author_quote = $(this).children(".a_quote").text();

    if (modal.css('display') == 'none') {
      modal_text.append("<p>" + author_quote + "</p>");
      modal.show()
    }
  });

  $(".close_quote").click(function() {
    modal.hide();
    modal_text.empty()
  });

});
```

```css
body{
  font-size: 20px;
}

tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

thead {
  background-color: #337AB7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #797979;
}

td {
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

th {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#hidden_container {
  display: none;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 900;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}

#hidden_container > h4 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.close_quote {
  background-color: #337AB7;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Last</td>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td>Born</td>
      <td>Died</td>
      <td>Quotes</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>George</td>
      <td>Orwell</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>Motihari</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>In a time of universal deceit - telling the truth is a revolutionary act.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Charles</td>
      <td>Dickens</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>Landport</td>
      <td>Higham</td>
      <td>It was the best of times, it was the worst of times.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Austen</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Steventon Rectory</td>
      <td>Winchester</td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="hidden_container">
  <button class="close_quote">X</button>
  <h4>Author Quote</h4>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quote_cell` is an array, so you'll need to wrap it in an `each()` block, otherwise the text value is cumulative.

```
$(quote_cell).each(function() {
    var this = $(this);

    this.wrapInner("<p class='a_quote'></p>");

    if (this.text().trim() == "") {
        this.append("<span>No quote available</span>");
    } else {
        this.children().css('display', 'none')
        this.append("<span>View Quotes</span>");
    }

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to  use loop  to iterate through all **quote_cell** objects.

```
$(quote_cell).each(function() {
    // your code
});
```